# CSS: Css style not being applied to link

Tags: html, css

I have a frustrating problem, one particular css style is not being applied to a link `<a>` tag.

The element i am talking about is a hover, which is applied to the header of my sidebar (is also a toggle). The hover applies to the header perfectly, but it also seems to apply to the 1st and 2nd sub-header(in the toggle) also. Which is causing to be a pain.

[image]

As you can see from the image above. The grey box(hover) over pending is not meant to be there.

I have changed the div from outside the ul tag to inside, i have renamed the id's and classes, but i cannot get rid of the box. The only way i can 100% get rid of the box is to remove the header:hover from my css, which works but i do not want to do that.

```css
.header:hover {
  background-color: #555e60;
}
```

```html
<a id="order" class="header" href="#"><h3 id="orderr">Orders</h3></span></a>
<div id="Order_div" style="display: none;">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <div>
      <li id='Red' class="order"><a class="sb" href="Franchise-account-orders.php">Overview</a></li>
      <li id='Blue' class="order"><a class="sb" href="admin_panel.php">Pending</a></li>
      <li id='Green' class="order"><a class="sb" href="admin_panel.php"> Accepted</a></li>
      <li id='Purple' class="order"><a class="sb" href="admin_panel.php"> Completed</a></li>
      <li id='Yellow' class="order"><a class="sb" href="admin_panel.php"> Declined</a></li>
    </div>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: as a quick test, have you removed the `:hover` from the CSS and made it just say `.header { background-color:#55e60;`?  This may show that your `.header` is actually in the wrong spot to begin with

Comment: try .header:first:hover {...your style...}

Comment: @ntgCleaner I just tried that, all is does is change the bg of the header. and makes the box i am trying to get rid of permanent

Comment: @MauricioMoraes just tried that thanks. Same result as above

Comment: @Blue, Yes, that should show you that your header is positioned incorrectly.  Now you can go into your inspector and find out why it's there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 issues in your html:

1. It looks like there is a broken `</span>` inside your link.
2. The other (that is causing the issue) is the `h3` inside the link.
   The browser's default style for the title is overriding your style.

Remove the `<h3>` and it will work.

Now you can style the `<span>` the way you want.

Take a look:

```css
.header:hover{
    background-color:#555e60;
}
```

```html
<a href='' class='header'><h3>With H3</h3></a>

<a href='' class='header'>Without H3</a>
```

Comment: Great that worked. I am not even sure why that span was there. thank you much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome, @Blue. I also made some edits to the question to make it clearer. If you find you can improve it better, it'll be great for people with similar problems in the future. I also didn't know about this combination of a header tag inside a link tag. markup can be deceiving.